# Why C# .Net doesn't support icons larger than 16x16?

Tags: c#, icons

In my project in C# all icons are in different sizes, but even 256x256 icons look like 16x16 in all forms.

Icons are very small. Has this problem a solution? I need larger icons. I set icons by Visual Studio wizard

Comment: There is about a thousand ways to display icons, you will need to be more specific about your way of doing it to get any help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
Icon sizedIcon = new Icon(Resources.ResourceIcon, new Size(64,64));
```

or try this:

```
Image img = new Icon(Properties.Resources.myIcon, width, height).ToBitmap();
```

Comment: Thanks you.I think it must work.but before that I get this exception : "Additional information: Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon"!

Comment: @user3807060:- For this error you have to try saving it to a PNG and using this free service for [conversion](http://www.convertico.com/)

Comment: I solved my exception but the size problem still exist